# trying to update a value and get it after being updated in a while loop

Tags: java, android

When I output  pW it gives me the original value

```
    double plateWt = wWeight - bWval;

    while (plateWt > 200 && plate100val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 200;
        plate100 ++;
        plate100val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 90 && plate45val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 90;
        plate45 ++;
        plate45val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 70 && plate35val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 70;
        plate35 ++;
        plate35val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 50 && plate25val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 50;
        plate25 ++;
        plate25val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 20 && plate10val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 20;
        plate10 ++;
        plate10val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 10 && plate5val > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 10;
        plate5 ++;
        plate5val --;
    }
    while (plateWt > 5 && plateQval > 0) {
        plateWt = plateWt - 5;
        plateQ ++;
        plateQval --;
    }
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "PlateWeight value: " + plateWt);
    double pw = plateWt;
    warmupPlatesOneTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pw));
```

11-25 15:16:16.867: I/LOG_TAG(21569): PlateWeight value: 5.0
11-25 15:16:16.883: I/LOG_TAG(21569): PlateWeight value: 10.0
11-25 15:16:17.121: I/LOG_TAG(21569): PlateWeight value: 45.0
11-25 15:16:17.145: I/LOG_TAG(21569): PlateWeight value: 45.0

Comment: Can you give the starting values for the variables?

Comment: original plateWt = 45, plate10val = 2, plate5val = 2

Comment: Indent your code properly, and use a debugger.

Comment: Log value changes from 5 to 10 to 45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess I'd say it'll running correctly the first time (resulting in 5)
After that, assuming global variables, the while loops will not execute.
Stick a break point into the code and step through it to check

Comment: I figured it out.  My plateValues were running out because of multiple calls to the function.

Answer (score -1):

Put log statements and make sure that the while loops are being entered and executed and wats plate10 value??

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: There was no option to comment shown up. So i answered. Need not be a reason to downvote.